# log smooth curve vs pointed node curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

F.Kato has a statement said that  a log smooth curve $f:(X, M,\alpha)\to (k,N,\beta)$ where $k$ is an algebraic closed field  and $N$ is some fine log structure on $k$,   is equvalent to pointed node curve in a paper "Log sooth deformation and moduli of log smooth curves". I am quite confused with the log structure $N$ on k, when one associate a log smooth curve to a pointed node curve.

Let's consider the following example, $X$ has only one double point $x$, and only one marked point $s$, and  $x\neq s$.  Let $A=k[t_1, t_2]/(t_1t_2)$,  $U=Spec (A)$ be an etale neighborhood of $x$ , with $x= (0,0)$, we see that the  log structure over  $U$ is     defined by the following  $\alpha:M_U:=k^*\oplus N^2 \to A $ by $\alpha(k_1,n_1,n_2)=  k_1t_1^{n_1}t_2^{n_2}$, and the log structure $N:=k^*\oplus \mathbb{N}$  and the map $\beta:N\to k $ defined by  $\beta(k_1,0)=k_1$, and $\beta(k_1,n)=0$ for $n>0$.
The map $f$ on the monoid is defined by the following $f^0:N\to M_U$, $f^0(k_1,n)=(k_1,n,n)$.

On the other hand  Let $B=k[T]$ , $V=Spec(B)$, be an etale neighborhood of $s$, with $s=(0)$. Then the log structure on V  is $M_V:=k^*\oplus \mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha(k_1,n)=k_1T^n$.

Now F. Kato claimed  one extend $M_U$, $M_V$ to $X$, and define $M:=M_U\oplus_{\mathcal{O}^{\times}_{X}} M_V$, then  $(X, M, \alpha)$ is log smooth over  $(k, N, \beta)$. My question is how to define the map $f^0 : N\to M$ on the monoid? Over $U$, it is already given above. But what about over V, it seem that it is impossible to define such a map, for one need to satisfy the following relation:
$ \alpha\circ f^0= i\circ \beta$, where $i: k\to k[T]$ is the natural map. 
And one fine that $\alpha\circ f^0(k_1, n)=i(0)=0 $ for $n>0$, however $0\notin Imge( \alpha)$, so it is impossible to define $f^0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really explained your notation, but it seems that you are covering the log curve $X$ with two neighborhoods $U$ and $V$, where $U$ contains a node, and $V$ contains a log point.  I think the problem with your definition of $M_V$ is that you forgot about the nontrivial log structure on the base log scheme.  If I'm not mistaken, the neighborhood a log point on the curve should have log structure associated to $k^* \times \mathbb{N}^2$ instead of $k^* \times \mathbb{N}$, with $\alpha(k_1,m,n) = k_1 0^m T^n$ and $f^0(k_1,m) = (k_1,m,0)$.

Comment: @Carnahan, you are right, I made a mistake about the log structue near the marked point. Thank you for your help.